# Flask-SQLALCHEMY: psycopg2 Operational Error - Server closed connection unexpectedly after a while

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using python 3.7 running API server using `Flask-restplus 0.12.1`, `SQLAlchemy==1.2.14` and `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2`
After few hours of idle time when the server is not processing requests; when a new request comes in to the system the very first request fails to get addressed. But after refresh or resend the request the application responds as it can connect to db next time.

I see the below issue in my logs.

```
error while fetching **********. Reason: (psycopg2.OperationalError) server closed the connection unexpectedly
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Here are my configuration parameters set while initializing db.

```
    # size of the database pool. Defaults to 5
    flask_app.config[constants.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE] = 25
    # connection timeout in secs
    flask_app.config[constants.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT] = 300
    flask_app.config[constants.CORS_HEADERS] = 'Content-Type'
```

How do I get around this issue? What is the right configuration parameter to use for mitigating this issue caused after a period of idleness. Help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- pesimistic approach: set `pool_pre_ping=True` argument (`constants.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_PRE_PING` in your notation) that make sqlalchemy to check if the connection is alive before checkout. If not, it will be refreshed.
- optimistic approach: set `pool_recycle=3600` argument (`constants.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE` in your notation) that "prevents the pool from using a particular connection that has passed a certain age" (3600s in my example).

More background in sqlalchemy docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects